# shifting array elements to right?

Tags: c#

I can't use a built-in function for this, I must use my own logic.

I've done element shifting to the left side, but the right side doesn't work for me. Not sure why.

My method for left:

```
public int[] shiftLeft(int[] arr) {
    int[] demo = new int[arr.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        demo[index] = arr[i + 1];
        index++;
    }
    return demo;
}
```

and my attempt for the right shifting:

```
public int[] shiftRight(int[] arr) {
    int[] demo = new int[arr.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        demo[index] = arr[(i - 1 > 0) ? i - 1 : 0];
        index++;
    }
    return demo;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

By shifting I mean:

you have an array, `1 2 3 4 5 6`
Shifting it to left by one: `2 3 4 5 6 1`
Shifting it to right by one: `6 1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: The left shift will not work either, as written.

Comment: You need to implement a standard circular buffer. Look It up on Wikipedia.

Comment: but if you use someone's answer, it won't be your own logic :(

Comment: @Jonesy Already knew someone would post this ;) but damn its true.

Comment: You're not doing it right. Use standard circular buffer logic. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: Please tell me why you can't use a built-in function for this ???

Comment: @FrankPfattheicher Because the class did not learn it, I think im one of the ones whom knows built in functions here, she only wants arrays  with basic .Length var, and loops.

Comment: @richard that's an interesting suggestion. So, in this case, would you just write over the array starting at the off-set position, not worrying about "shifting" in any real sense?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
//right shift with modulus
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    demo[(i+1) % demo.length] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: I personally don't really like this answer; the comment _right shift with modulus_ is required because it's hard to tell what the code is doing if you don't look carefully. Answer from @MarcinJuraszek is more simple/readable IMHO

Comment: I disagree, since this solution is cleaner in the way that the last/first items are not treated differently than the others. It's also easy to implement the left shift with modulus. I would also argue that modulus is pretty straight forward for anyone who writes code for a living or as a hobby.

Comment: It's more concise and more clever, but I agree it's also more difficult to read than the verbose version. If you put it in some utils class, why not though.

Comment: Utils class? `Array.Copy` version only.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek in this case, of course, I just mean that's the principle I'd go by - if a piece of code is a bit cryptic, but encapsulated in some library class and all you normally need to know is that it works, readability is not much of a problem.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to go:

```
public int[] shiftLeft(int[] arr) 
{
    int[] demo = new int[arr.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++) 
    {
        demo[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }

    demo[demo.Length - 1] = arr[0];

    return demo;
}

public int[] shiftRight(int[] arr) 
{
    int[] demo = new int[arr.Length];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++) 
    {
        demo[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }

    demo[0] = arr[demo.Length - 1];

    return demo;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for arbitrary number of shifts, @Robert Fricke does

Answer (score 4):

LINQ solution, just to add some diversity.

```
static int[] LeftShift(int[] array)
{            
    // all elements except for the first one... and at the end, the first one. to array.
    return array.Skip(1).Concat(array.Take(1)).ToArray();
}

static int[] RightShift(int[] array)
{
    // the last element (because we're skipping all but one)... then all but the last one.
    return array.Skip(array.Length - 1).Concat(array.Take(array.Length - 1)).ToArray();
}
```

Probably not recommended if performance matters (for large arrays).

I realize that the OP is not supposed to use a "built-in function".

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static int[] shiftRight(int[] arr){

      int[] demo = new int[arr.Length];

      for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length - 2; i++)
      {
          demo[i + 1] = arr[i];
      }

      demo[0] = arr[arr.Length - 1];
      return demo;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you need to special case the left shift of the first element.  For every element but the first the new index of the value will be `oldIndex - 1`.  This is essentially what the loop is doing.  However the first element has a new index of `oldLength - 1`.  This needs to be special cased somewhere in the code base.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public int[] ShiftRight(int[] arr) 
{
    int[] demo = new int[arr.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
        demo[i] = arr[i == 0 ? (arr.Length - 1) : (i - 1)];
    }
    return demo; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Arra.Copy...

```
public int[] shiftLeft(int[] arr) {
var result = new int[arr.Length];
Array.Copy(arr, 1, result, 0, arr.Length - 1);
result[arr.Length - 1] = arr[0];
return result;
```

}

```
    public int[] shiftRight(int[] arr) {
  var result = new int[arr.Length];
  Array.Copy(arr, 0, result, 1, arr.Length - 1);
  result[0] = arr[arr.Length - 1];
  return result;
}
```

Comment: From the bottom of the question: "I can't use a built-in function for this, I must use my own logic."

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use this code.  You can rewrites to the array extension method.

```
public static T[] Shift<T>(T[] array, int shiftValue)
{       
    var newArray = new T[array.Length];
    shiftValue -= array.Length;
    if(shiftValue < 0)
    {
        shiftValue*=-1;
    }


    for(var i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
    {
        var index = (i + shiftValue) % array.Length;

        newArray[i] = array[index]; 
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works for anyone seeing this post :

```
private int[] shiftLinear(int[] linArray, int shift){   
    int length = linArray.Length;
    int[] shifted = new int[length];
    shift = shift % length;
    if (shift >= 0) {
        for (int n = shift ; n < length; n++) shifted[n] = linArray[n-shift];   
        if (shift != 0)  for (int n = 0; n < shift; n++) shifted[n] = linArray[length-1-n]; 
    } else {
        for (int n = 0 ; n < length+shift; n++) shifted[n] = linArray[n-shift];   
        for (int n = length+shift; n < length ; n++) shifted[n] = linArray[n-length-shift]; 
    }
    return shifted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using external array;

```
public static int[] right(int[] A)
{
     var tempo = A[0];
     for(var i=0; i<A.Length-1; i++)
     {
         var yolo = A[i + 1];
         A[i + 1] = tempo;
         tempo = yolo;
     }
     A[0] = tempo;
     return A;
 }

public static int[] left(int[] A)
{
    var tempo = A[A.Length - 1];
    for (var i = A.Length - 1; i >0; i--)
    {
          var yolo = A[i - 1];
          A[i -1] = tempo;
          tempo = yolo;
    }
    A[A.Length - 1] = tempo;
    return A;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int[] shiftRight(int[] arr) 
{
    int[] demo = new int[arr.length];

    Array.Copy(arr,arr.Length-1,demo,0,1); // Copy last position to first
    Array.Copy(arr,0,demo,1,arr.Length-1); // Copy the rest shifted one       

    return demo;
}
```

Comment: From the bottom of the question: "I can't use a built-in function for this, I must use my own logic."